# Apache 403 Forbidden: Access is denied error

Tags: apache

I've been given access to a web server running Centos, PHP 7 and Apache 2. I have uploaded a Drupal site to it, but when I visit the site in my browser, I see;

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

In order to allow a user to upload files via SFTP, I have created an SSH user 'webuser', create a group 'www-data', assigned the group to the user and set the file permissions to allow that group to be able to upload files into /var/www/html.

I have made some changes to the Apache config, mainly changing AllowOveride to All.

The folder contain the Drupal site is /var/www/html/drupal.

/var/www/html is owned by apache:www-data

/var/www/html is owned by webuser:www-data

I'm a little stumped as to why I'm seeing this error.

I have placed test files in the folder such as test.txt and a php file which should output phpinfo(), but these don't work, indicating the problem isn't specific to Drupal but rather the server configuration.

As requested, here is the .htaccess file;

```
#
# Apache/PHP/Drupal settings:
#

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|install|make|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|twig|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|yml)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|^(\.(?!well-known).*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock))$|^#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)$">
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order allow,deny
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

# Add correct encoding for SVGZ.
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz

# Most of the following PHP settings cannot be changed at runtime. See
# sites/default/default.settings.php and
# Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel::bootEnvironment() for settings that can be
# changed at runtime.

# PHP 5, Apache 1 and 2.
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value assert.active                   0
  php_flag session.auto_start               off
  php_value mbstring.http_input             pass
  php_value mbstring.http_output            pass
  php_flag mbstring.encoding_translation    off
  # PHP 5.6 has deprecated $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA and produces warnings if this is
  # not set.
  php_value always_populate_raw_post_data   -1
</IfModule>

# Requires mod_expires to be enabled.
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

  # Cache all files for 2 weeks after access (A).
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

  <FilesMatch \.php$>
    # Do not allow PHP scripts to be cached unless they explicitly send cache
    # headers themselves. Otherwise all scripts would have to overwrite the
    # headers set by mod_expires if they want another caching behavior. This may
    # fail if an error occurs early in the bootstrap process, and it may cause
    # problems if a non-Drupal PHP file is installed in a subdirectory.
    ExpiresActive Off
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# Set a fallback resource if mod_rewrite is not enabled. This allows Drupal to
# work without clean URLs. This requires Apache version >= 2.2.16. If Drupal is
# not accessed by the top level URL (i.e.: http://example.com/drupal/ instead of
# http://example.com/), the path to index.php will need to be adjusted.
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  FallbackResource /index.php
</IfModule>

# Various rewrite rules.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
  # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
  # you don't bounce between http and https.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

  # Make sure Authorization HTTP header is available to PHP
  # even when running as CGI or FastCGI.
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

  # Block access to "hidden" directories whose names begin with a period. This
  # includes directories used by version control systems such as Subversion or
  # Git to store control files. Files whose names begin with a period, as well
  # as the control files used by CVS, are protected by the FilesMatch directive
  # above.
  #
  # NOTE: This only works when mod_rewrite is loaded. Without mod_rewrite, it is
  # not possible to block access to entire directories from .htaccess because
  # <DirectoryMatch> is not allowed here.
  #
  # If you do not have mod_rewrite installed, you should remove these
  # directories from your webroot or otherwise protect them from being
  # downloaded.
  RewriteRule "/\.|^\.(?!well-known/)" - [F]

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/foo will be redirected to http://www.example.com/foo)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/foo will be redirected to http://example.com/foo)
  # uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Redirect common PHP files to their new locations.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?/(install.php) [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?/(rebuild.php)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !core
  RewriteRule ^ %1/core/%2 [L,QSA,R=301]

  # Rewrite install.php during installation to see if mod_rewrite is working
  RewriteRule ^core/install.php core/install.php?rewrite=ok [QSA,L]

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  # For security reasons, deny access to other PHP files on public sites.
  # Note: The following URI conditions are not anchored at the start (^),
  # because Drupal may be located in a subdirectory. To further improve
  # security, you can replace '!/' with '!^/'.
  # Allow access to PHP files in /core (like authorize.php or install.php):
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/core/[^/]*\.php$
  # Allow access to test-specific PHP files:
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/core/modules/system/tests/https?.php
  # Allow access to Statistics module's custom front controller.
  # Copy and adapt this rule to directly execute PHP files in contributed or
  # custom modules or to run another PHP application in the same directory.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/core/modules/statistics/statistics.php$
  # Deny access to any other PHP files that do not match the rules above.
  # Specifically, disallow autoload.php from being served directly.
  RewriteRule "^(.+/.*|autoload)\.php($|/)" - [F]

  # Rules to correctly serve gzip compressed CSS and JS files.
  # Requires both mod_rewrite and mod_headers to be enabled.
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

    # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      # Serve correct encoding type.
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# Various header fixes.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Disable content sniffing, since it's an attack vector.
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
  # Disable Proxy header, since it's an attack vector.
  RequestHeader unset Proxy
</IfModule>
```

I'm not sure it's a .htaccess issue though. The drupal site resides in /var/www/html/drupal and is accessed by placing 'drupal' on the end of the URL. I've places a simple HTML file inside /var/www/html and tried accessing that using just the domain name, and even that doesn't load.

As this is Centos and Ubuntu, I've removed my www-data group, added my user to the apache group, and set permissions on the folders so apache:apache is the owner:group.

```
drwxrwxr-x.  5 root   root     47 Mar  4 11:40 .
drwxr-xr-x. 21 root   root   4096 Feb 28 16:50 ..
drwxrwxr-x.  2 root   root      6 Jun 22  2018 cgi-bin
drwxrwsr-x.  3 apache apache   38 Mar  5 16:50 html
```

and on /var/www/html

```
drwxrwsr-x.  3 apache apache   38 Mar  5 16:50 .
drwxrwxr-x.  5 root   root     47 Mar  4 11:40 ..
drwxrwsr-x. 11 apache apache 4096 Mar  5 16:17 drupal
-rwxr-xr-x   1 apache apache   47 Mar  5 16:50 index.html
```

and on /var/www/html/drupal

```
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache    262 Apr 25  2018 autoload.php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache   2740 Apr 25  2018 composer.json
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache 161072 Apr 25  2018 composer.lock
drwxr-sr-x. 12 apache apache   4096 Apr 25  2018 core
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache   1025 Apr 25  2018 .csslintrc
drwxr-sr-x.  3 apache apache     16 Jul  3  2018 docker
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache   1413 Apr 25  2018 docker-compose-staging.yml
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache    167 Nov  2 10:52 docker-compose.yml
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache    357 Apr 25  2018 .editorconfig
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache    151 Apr 25  2018 .eslintignore
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache     41 Apr 25  2018 .eslintrc.json
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache   3858 Apr 25  2018 .gitattributes
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache    169 May  3  2018 .gitignore
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache   7866 Apr 25  2018 .htaccess
drwxr-sr-x.  7 apache apache   4096 Jun  4  2018 html
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache   2306 Apr 25  2018 .ht.router.php
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache    549 Apr 25  2018 index.php
drwxr-sr-x.  7 apache apache     88 Mar 15  2018 libraries
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache  18092 Nov 16  2016 LICENSE.txt
drwxr-sr-x. 66 apache apache   4096 Oct  8 16:02 modules
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache     23 Oct 29 16:14 phpinfo.php
drwxr-sr-x.  2 apache apache     24 Feb 20  2018 profiles
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache   5889 Apr 25  2018 README.txt
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache   1596 Apr 25  2018 robots.txt
drwxr-sr-x.  3 apache apache    145 Jun  4  2018 sites
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache      5 Mar  5 16:17 test.txt
drwxr-sr-x.  5 apache apache     93 Oct  9 08:32 themes
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache    848 Apr 25  2018 update.php
drwxr-sr-x. 17 apache apache   4096 Apr 25  2018 vendor
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 apache apache   4555 Apr 25  2018 web.config
```

In an effort to resolve this, I have created a virtual host;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                                                                                                                     
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/staging                                                                                                                                                    
        ServerName servername.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com                                                                                                                                                
        ServerAlias servername.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com                                                                                                                                               

        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/staging>                                                                                                                                                     
                Options +FollowSymLinks -Includes                                                                                                                                                      
                AllowOverride All                                                                                                                                                                      
        </Directory>                                                                                                                                                                                   
</VirtualHost>
```

I've created the folder /var/www/html/staging and placed a simple HTML file inside it, I still see the same error when I visit the url in my browser, and I see no errors logged in the Apache error_log file.

Comment: Sounds like a possible .htaccess problem.  Can you update your question to include the contents of the .htaccess file that's in the directory you are trying to access?

Comment: I've added additional information.

Comment: Have you checked the Apache logs?  Are you using virtual hosts in Apache? Did you install Drupal directly to the current location, or did you use mv to put it there?

Comment: Another thing, if you have access to the httpd.conf file you should not be using .htaccess anyway.  So the AllowOverride directive should be set to None, and all the configuration should be done directly in httpd.conf

Comment: I uploaded the Drupal files via SFTP. I have checked the Apache error log and there are no errors being reported. Currently we are not using virtual hosts.

Comment: I have also removed the Drupal folder and its contents, re-created the folder and placed a single HTML file inside it, that won't display in a browser either. There was a pre-existing install of Drupal in the folder when I took on the server, it worked, I deleted it to upload new files, so this is something I have done, I just don't know what.

Comment: I have tried to create a virtual host and pointed it to a different folder, but I'm seeing the same issue and no errors logged in the error_log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189477/discussion-between-david-watson-and-shepparddigital).

Comment: Thanks. I've stopped Apache and I still see the same error, so I think the issue is actually somewhere else, I've asked the person that setup the network/server in Azure to look at it.